# Unexpected white button while using ToptabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am new in Xamarin.Forms. I tried to use TopTabbedPage to make top tab navigation template for both ios and Android. However the navigation shows the issue in ios:

[image]

It looks like there are two buttons over the tab position. Source code is as follow:

```
<forms:TopTabbedPage  
           ...
             Title="Time Clock">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Time Clock" >
            <x:Arguments>
                <tc:ClockInOutPage/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Report" >
            <x:Arguments>
                <tc:TimeReportPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</forms:TopTabbedPage>
```

It works good in Android. Any hint to fix it? Or would it be better to use a custom renderer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of this plugin? I found a similar [issue](https://github.com/NAXAM/toptabbedpage-xamarin-forms/issues/37) in Github.

Comment: Oh Thanks! Finally make it work using 0.0.3.13-pre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jack I finally used the version [0.0.3.13-pre](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms/0.0.3.13-pre). It works as what I want for my project.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).